# How to change an embedded app that was created using shopify cli to a non embedded app?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

Well basically what all steps should I follow to make it so that it doesn't render inside admin panel that is inside the iframe tag.

I have tried disabling the embed app option in  settings tab in shopify partners dashboard. But that didn't do the trick.